# Solution of $(1-x)^p= x$ in $(0,1/n)$

Tags: polynomials, elementary-functions

Let $n,p$ be positive integers.
The equation 
$$
(1-x)^p = x
$$
has a unique solution $x_p$ in the interval $(0,1)$. This follows by the monotonicity properties of $(1-x)^p$ and $x$.

My question is: given $n$ is it possible to determine $p$ such that $x_p$ satisfies 
$$
0< x_p \le \frac 1n?
$$

Bernoullis inequality 
$$
(1-x)^p \ge 1 - px, \quad x\in (0,1),
$$
only yields a lower bound
$$
x_p \ge \frac1{p+1}.
$$

Comment: Do you have more context about $p$? e.g. $p\geq 1$

Comment: It's stated $p$ is a positive integer

Comment: Oh yes... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $n$, it is the set of $p$ so that $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^p\leq\frac 1 n$$

Taking the log of both sides, this means:

$$p(\log (n-1)-\log n) \leq -\log n$$
Since we are dealing with negative numbers, that means:

$$p\geq \frac{\log n}{\log n-\log(n-1)}$$

Comment: I feel stupid now, not to think about logarithms 8)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since $0\lt x\lt 1$,$$(1-x)^p=x\iff 1-x=x^{1/p}\iff x+x^{1/p}-1=0.$$
Then, letting $f(x)$ be the LHS, we have for $x\gt 0$
$$f'(x)=1+\frac{1}{p}x^{1/p-1}\gt 0.$$
Hence, we know $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Hence, with $f(0)=-1\lt 0$ and $f(1)=1\gt 0$, we know 
$$0\lt x_p\le \frac 1n\iff f\left(\frac 1n\right)\ge 0\iff \frac 1n+\left(\frac 1n\right)^{1/p}-1\ge 0.$$

Solving this for $p$ will give you the same answer as the one Thomas Andrews gives.